# Cannot generate Prisma client, outputDir.endsWith is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, nexus, prisma

I'm using Next.js, Prisma, and Nexus (nexus-plugin-prisma) and have been trying to generate a Prisma client to no avail. Whenever I am running `npx prisma generate` I've been getting the following error:

```
TypeError: outputDir.endsWith is not a function
    at getDotPrismaDir (...)
    at generateClient (...)
```

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^2.19.0",
    "apollo-server-micro": "^2.22.2",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "nexus": "^1.0.0",
    "nexus-plugin-prisma": "^0.33.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "prisma": "^2.20.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  }
}
```

I've been following these steps as suggested by the Prisma CLI (to step 3):

```
Next steps:
1. Set the DATABASE_URL in the .env file to point to your existing database. If your database has no tables yet, read https://pris.ly/d/getting-started
2. Set the provider of the datasource block in schema.prisma to match your database: postgresql, mysql or sqlite.
3. Run prisma db pull to turn your database schema into a Prisma data model.
4. Run prisma generate to install Prisma Client. You can then start querying your database.
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Updating `@prisma/client` and `prisma` to the latest version i.e. **2.20.1** should solve this.

Comment: Yeah, version mismatch was the bottleneck, turns out I had to downgrade ``prisma`` to be compatible with ``nexus-plugin-prisma``!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the version for `prisma` needs to be the same as the version of `@prisma/client` provided by `nexus-plugin-prisma`. Changing `prisma` to `2.19.x` and generating the client worked!

Note: You also don't need to install `@prisma/client` individually as this comes with the plugin.

Comment: It seems that you are using an older version of `nexus-plugin-prisma`. `@prisma/client` doesn't come bundled anymore in the newer versions.

Comment: @Ryan I'm using version ``0.33.0``, wasn't this released only a few days ago?